# How to fix "Class not found" in Cordova?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova, plugins

I cloned this **Cordova project** from github that tests `cordova-plugin-hello-c` 
but I'm getting `'Class Not found'` when I test it on my emulator.

Cordova project link : https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-hello-c-test

Cordova-plugin-hello-c: https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-hello-c

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question

Comment: can you provide the log file, if you can paste it here it would be great

Comment: Please see this issue: https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/issues/683

Comment: @DaveAlden Thank u !